# Saving selected item from listview into string

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

First of all I am new to the C# programming. I have a listview with two columns ("Name of a procedure" and "Price") with items already populated in listview. What I would like to do is to save the "Price" of selected item into variable on button click. What I have come up with was:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
string Price = listView.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
}
```

But this just saves "System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection" into the string. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: This is collection and you should select first element or parse collection somehow else to get elements from it.

Comment: use `(listView.SelectedItems[0] as <<Your Model>>).Price`

Comment: Better use `var price = ((YourModelItem)listView.SelectedItem)?.Price;`

Comment: @Clemens This works, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Clemens I used ((YourModelItem)listView.SelectedItem).Price instead of  listView.SelectedItems[0].ToString();